# CSS for directives in AngularJs1.6.4+UI-Bootstrap3.0.0 is not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use ui-bootstrap-3.0.0 with angularjs-1.6.4

I managed to display datepicker directive in html page but it is coming with much larger width and height (1900 * 800)

I am not able to find if any css or js file is missing.

I have copied code from *https://morgul.github.io/ui-bootstrap4/#!#datepicker*

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app='demo'>

<head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Hello</button>

    <style>
        .full button span {
            background-color: limegreen;
            border-radius: 32px;
            color: black;
        }

        .partially button span {
            background-color: orange;
            border-radius: 32px;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
        <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

        <h4>Inline</h4>
        <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
            <div uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="card" datepicker-options="options"></div>
        </div>

        <hr />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="today()">Today</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" ng-click="setDate(2009, 7, 24)">2009-08-24</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" ng-click="toggleMin()" uib-tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-touch.js"></script>

    <script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);


app.controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.today = function() {
      $scope.dt = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.clear = function() {
      $scope.dt = null;
    };

    $scope.options = {
      customClass: getDayClass,
      minDate: new Date(),
      showWeeks: true
    };

    // Disable weekend selection
    function disabled(data) {
      var date = data.date,
        mode = data.mode;
      return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
    }

    $scope.toggleMin = function() {
      $scope.options.minDate = $scope.options.minDate ? null : new Date();
    };

    $scope.toggleMin();

    $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
      $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
    };

    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    var afterTomorrow = new Date(tomorrow);
    afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    $scope.events = [
      {
        date: tomorrow,
        status: 'full'
      },
      {
        date: afterTomorrow,
        status: 'partially'
      }
    ];

    function getDayClass(data) {
      var date = data.date,
        mode = data.mode;
      if (mode === 'day') {
        var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
          var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

          if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
            return $scope.events[i].status;
          }
        }
      }

      return '';
    }
  });
```

**ui-bootstrap-tpls-3.0.0.min.js**

Downloaded from *https://morgul.github.io/ui-bootstrap4/#!#getting_started* (with template)

Answer (score 0):

It is just a workaround and discussing here (to help others if got same problem) because i have not found its clear solution.

ui-bootstrap4 has 
**ui-bootstrap/template/datepicker/day.html** as

```
...
      <th>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-left uib-left" ng-click="move(-1)" tabindex="-1">
          <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa-svg-icon">
            <svg width="1792" height="1792" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1427 301l-531 531 531 531q19 19 19 45t-19 45l-166 166q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-742-742q-19-19-19-45t19-45l742-742q19-19 45-19t45 19l166 166q19 19 19 45t-19 45z"/></svg>
          </i>
          <span class="sr-only">previous</span>
        </button>
      </th>

...
```

Here svg width and height is 1792.

Same with **ui-bootstrap/template/carousel/carousel.html** as

```
<div class="carousel-inner" ng-transclude></div>
<a role="button" href class="left carousel-control" ng-click="prev()" ng-class="{ disabled: isPrevDisabled() }" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa-svg-icon">
    <svg width="1792" height="1792" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1427 301l-531 531 531 531q19 19 19 45t-19 45l-166 166q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-742-742q-19-19-19-45t19-45l742-742q19-19 45-19t45 19l166 166q19 19 19 45t-19 45z"/></svg>
  </span>
  <span class="sr-only">previous</span>
</a>
<a role="button" href class="right carousel-control" ng-click="next()" ng-class="{ disabled: isNextDisabled() }" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa-svg-icon">
    <svg width="1792" height="1792" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1363 877l-742 742q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-166-166q-19-19-19-45t19-45l531-531-531-531q-19-19-19-45t19-45l166-166q19-19 45-19t45 19l742 742q19 19 19 45t-19 45z"/></svg>
  </span>
  <span class="sr-only">next</span>
</a>
<ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
  <li ng-repeat="slide in slides | orderBy:indexOfSlide track by $index" ng-class="{ active: isActive(slide) }" ng-click="select(slide)">
    <span class="sr-only">slide {{ $index + 1 }} of {{ slides.length }}<span ng-if="isActive(slide)">, currently active</span></span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

It's clear that ui-bootstrap4 has given templates height and width as 1792 which is not good.

Solved..
*Used custom template to override the ui-bootstrap/template/carousel/carousel.html using template-url attribute in  directive.*

**custom/template/carousel.html**

```
<div class="carousel-inner" ng-transclude></div>
<ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
  <li ng-repeat="slide in slides | orderBy:indexOfSlide track by $index" ng-class="{ active: isActive(slide) }" ng-click="select(slide)">
    <span class="sr-only">slide {{ $index + 1 }} of {{ slides.length }}<span ng-if="isActive(slide)">, currently active</span></span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**Used as:**

```
    <div uib-carousel active="0" interval="1000" no-wrap="false" template-url="./custom/template/carousel.html">
...
</div>
```